# Trying to understand the SYSCALL 5 example, the order of the literals % placeholder is confusing

Tags: mips, mips64, edumips64

I'm learning MIPS64 and using EduMIPS64 simulator.

I understand the instructions of the following example, I tried to execute it cycle after cycle but I don't get how the compiler knows which number or string matches to corresponding placeholder and how all related to `format_str` so in the end of the `.code` section, it's enough to put the address of `format_str` in `r14`

I know that System calls expect that the address of their parameters is stored in register R14, but how all the others relate to this address(`format_str`)?

> For each `%s`, `%d` or `%i` placeholder, `SYSCALL 5` expects a
>   parameter, starting from the address of the previous one. When the
>   SYSCALL finds a placeholder for an integer parameter, it expects that
>   the corresponding parameter is an integer value, when if it finds a
>   placeholder for a string parameter, it expects as a parameter the
>   address of the string.

I tried understand it by the memory representation with no success.

```
            .data
format_str: .asciiz "%dth of %s:\n%s version %i.%i is being tested!"
s1:         .asciiz "June"
s2:         .asciiz "EduMIPS64"
fs_addr:    .space  4
            .word   5
s1_addr:    .space  4
s2_addr:    .space  4
            .word   0
            .word   5
test:
            .code
            daddi   r5, r0, format_str
            sw      r5, fs_addr(r0)
            daddi   r2, r0, s1
            daddi   r3, r0, s2
            sd      r2, s1_addr(r0)
            sd      r3, s2_addr(r0)
            daddi   r14, r0, fs_addr
            syscall 5
            syscall 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator doesn't really need to know anything about placeholders.

It knows where the format string and all the other values are located in the simulated memory (`fs_addr`), because you passed that address in `r14`. So the simulator could just take that address and map it to the corresponding address in the host machine's memory, cast the first two words at that address into a `const char*` and a `va_list`, and then call `vprintf`.

I don't know if that's what EduMIPS64 actually does, but that seems like one of the simpler solutions.

---

This shows what each of the placeholders in your example correspond to:

```
"%dth of %s:\n%s version %i.%i is being tested!"
 |       |    |           |  | 
 |       |    |           |  +-+
 |       |    |           +-+  |
 |       |    +----------+  |  |
 |       +-------------+ |  |  |
 +--------->.word   5  | |  |  | 
                       | |  |  |
s1_addr:    .space  4<-+ |  |  |
s2_addr:    .space  4<---+  |  |
            .word   0<------+  |
            .word   5<---------+
```

Comment: For example, if change the data from
`fs_addr:    .space 4
     .word 5`
s1_addr:    .space 4
s2_addr:    .space 4` 

to:
`fs_addr:    .space 4
`s1_addr:    .space 4
     .word 5
s2_addr:    .space 4` 
I replaced the order of '.word 5` and `s1_addr:    .space 4` so the print is:
`48th of 5:
EduMIPS64 version 0.5 is being tested!`

I don't understand why `48` in the beginning.

Comment: Well, that change makes no sense. You're now passing a string pointer where an integer parameter is expected, and an integer where a string pointer is expected. As for the "48" that gets printed, the low-order 16 bits of `s1`'s address probably happens to be `0x0030` (i.e. 48). But again, the change makes no sense, so you shouldn't read too much into the result.